# How to prove local minima are global?

Tags: functions, optimization

I have the function $f(x,y) = (x^2 - 4)^2 + y^2,$

which has two local minima at $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0).$ How can I prove that these are global minima?

Comment: If you've found all the minima, then the smallest is global. These are equally small. So if this is a list of all the minima, then these are the global minima.

Comment: In the particular case you gave, high school algebra is enough. The sum of two squares can't be negative, and can only be zero when each equals zero. Thus, since "$x^2 - 4 = 0$ and $y^2 = 0$" is possible, each solution to this pair of equations gives you a global minimum.

Comment: @mixedmath I'm afraid *'if you've found all the minima, then the smallest is global.'* is not precise enough. How about $x\mapsto 4x^2-x^4$...? It has one local minimum at $x=0$ but is it a global mnimum?

Answer (score 3):

We easily get $f(x,y)\ge 0$ and $$f(x,y)=0\iff x^2=4\;\wedge\;y=0\iff (x,y)=(-2,0)\;\vee\;(x,y)=(2,0).$$ Obviously $f(\pm 2,0)=0$, so local minima are also global.

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the gradient of $f$, you obtain $\nabla f(x,y)=(4x(x^{2}-4),2y)$. So you have $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$ as stationary points, and computing the function's Hessian you see that they are local minima.

Now observe that for any $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2\geq3$ you have $\nabla f(x,y)$ pointing out from the ball $B_3=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x^2+y^2\leq 3\}$ since $\langle\nabla f,(x,y)\rangle>0$.

So the function is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^{2}- B_3$ and you can apply Fermat's theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29

to see that they are the only possible global minima.

Comment: This method does not catch the case that the infimum is 'attained' at infinity.

Comment: @daw I know, but catch this particular function case. I will edit to explain better.