# proving that a point is a global minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have this cost function

$$
f(x,y,z)=0.5 \left(x^2+y^2+0.1(z^2)\right)+0.55z
$$

such that

$$x,y,z>0$$

$$x+y+z=1$$

I was given the point $(0.5,0.5,0)$ as a local minimum. How to I go along to prove/disprove this is also a global minimum.

Lagrange multipliers just gave me a max point.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your work with lagrange multipliers?

Comment: It gives me only one point and z<0 for that point. So it doesn't hold to the constraint.

Comment: is it not $x,y,z \geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The differential of your function:

$d(0.55 z + 0.5 (x^2 + y^2 + 0.1 z^2)) = x dx + y dy + (0.55 + 0.1 z) dz$

A global maximum (or minimum) either must be a **local maximum (or minimum)** in the interior of the domain, **or** must **lie on the boundary** of the domain (This is the Extreme Value Theorem). Local maxima and minima occur wherever the derivative of the function at that location is zero. These are "**critical points**" because they either have a derivative of zero or are a boundary point and are therefore nondifferentiable.

Therefore, the next step is to find the critical points.

The critical points of this function are:

Where $x=0$, $y=0$, and $(0.55 + 0.1 z)=0 \implies z=-5.5$ (not valid because z must be > 0)

and

The boundary points: $x=0$, $\space \space$ $y=0$, $\space \space$  $z=0$, $\space \space$$x=1$, $\space \space$$y=1$, $\space \space$ $z=1$ (every combination thereof is a boundary point; there are $2^3=8$ points total.)

We must check these points by evaluating $f(x,y,z)$ at each point to determine the minimum.

**Checking all points, we find that the minimum is at** $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Additional reading:

[According to the **Extreme Value Theorem**, if a function is continuous on a closed interval, a maximum and minimum exist. (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima)

see also [How to prove local minima are global?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943337/how-to-prove-local-minima-are-global)

[View the answer to this question on wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what%20are%20the%20critical%20points%20of%20f%28x%2Cy%2Cz%29%3D0.5%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B0.1%28z%5E2%29%29%2B0.55%7Cz%7C) (as kind of a hack I put in the z term as abs(z))

Comment: I understand, but that minimum does not satisfy the constraint x+y+z=1

Comment: You're right. Let me work on this a bit more

Comment: Is it enough to say that because the constraining function is monotonic, if we found a local minimum, it has to be a global minimum?
Or, if I plug in the z value from the constraining function to the cost function, I get a convex function, so any local minimum is a global one?

Answer (score 0):

Since the local min/max occurs either when the derivative is zero or on the boundary.

$$f_x'=0,f_y'=0,f_z'=0\implies (x,y,z)=(0,0,-5.5)$$

But $(0,0,-5.5)$ is not in the domain, hence the min/max if it exists is on the boundary.

The boundary of set $A$ given by $x+y+z=1$ and $x,y,z>0$ is the closure of $A$ because it doesn't have any interior points (if $a+b+c=1$ then $(a+\epsilon/3,b+\epsilon/3,c+\epsilon/3) \in B((a,b,c),\epsilon)$ but $a+b+c+\epsilon\neq 1$ so $(a+\epsilon/3,b+\epsilon/3,c+\epsilon/3)\not\in A$

The closure of $A$ is $x+y+z=1$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$

Now since we have $z=1-x-y$ for $x,y\geq 0,x+y\leq 1$

Now the extrema of function
$g(x,y)=f(x,y,1-x-y)$ on the domain $B = \{(x,y)|x,y\geq 0,x+y\leq 1\}$ is either on the boundary of B or when the derivative is zero

Is given by $g_x'=0,g_y'=0$ so $1.1x+0.1y=0.65$ and $1.1y+0.1x-0.65=0$ which only happens for $(x,y)=(0.65/1.2,0.65/1.2)$ but then $x+y>1$ so not in the domain $B$.

Now checking the boundary of $B$ which is $x=0,y\leq 1$ union $y=0,x\leq 1$ and $x+y=1,x,y>0$ in the first case (second is the same by symmetry) we have $h(y)=f(0,y,1-y)$ and $h'(y)=1.2y-0.65$ so we have $h$ decreasing up to $0.65/1.2$ and increasing otherwise; so the potential minimum is $h(0.65/1.2)$ now checking the last case $t(x) = f(x,1-x,0)=0.5(x^2+(1-x^2))$ we have $t'(x)=2x-1$ so the potential minimum occurs at $x=1/2$ at which $t(1/2)=1/4$ but $h(0.65/1.2)>1/4$ so $x=y=1/2,z=0$ is a minimum. (For additional rigour why didn't we have to consider $h(0),h(1),t(0),t(1)$ as potential min/max?)